# Crash when replacing filename extension

Tags: c++, string, replace

I'm trying to create strings that replace my .png and .jpg files in a directory (all files in it only contain these extensions) with .txt using the .replace command like so:

```
//say path is directory
path.replace(path.end()-3, path.end()-1, "txt");
```

It keeps crashing my program though, what am I doing wrong? It's finding the 'png' part properly, but the replacing is not working.

[image]

Here's what happens when I do this.

```
string a = dir.getPath(i); //this is ..\data\images\Test0.png
string b = dir.getPath(i).replace(dir.getPath(i).end()-3, dir.getPath(i).end(), "txt"); //crashes
```

[image]

Comment: I bet `dir.getPath(i)` returns a new string every time it's called. So `dir.getPath(i).end()-3` and `dir.getPath(i).end()` are two iterators into *different* strings, neither of which is the one you call `replace` on. Instead, do `a.replace(a.end()...)` - call `getPath` once, store the result in a variable, then manipulate that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace the last three characters, you need to provide a range that has three characters. Currently, your range is only two characters in size, i.e from `end()-3`, inclusive, to `end()-1`, *exclusive*.

```
string s("hello.png");
s.replace(s.end()-3, s.end(), "txt");
cout << s << endl;
```

In addition, you need to make sure that the length of the string is not less than three characters, otherwise accessing `end()-3` is undefined behavior.

Also, make sure that you do not use `dir.getPath(i)` multiple times, otherwise your `end()-3` iterator and `end()` iterator point to different strings. I.e.

```
string b = dir.getPath(i).replace(dir.getPath(i).end()-3, dir.getPath(i).end(), "txt"); // Crashes
//             ^^^^^^               ^^^^^^                  ^^^^^^^
//            Copy # 1             Copy # 2                 Copy # 3
```

needs to be

```
string b = dir.getPath(i);
b.replace(b.end()-3, b.end(), "txt"); // Does not crash
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/TYYXND)

Comment: @parameter That is strange. Try adding some printouts before and after, and check that the string is long enough for the replacement. If it's all good before you run this code snippet, run a memory profiler to make sure that the error that you see is not caused by some error from earlier on.

Comment: I'm thinking it's because I need to get the absolute path of the file, not relative, see updated question

Comment: @parameter That's it! You are using `dir.getPath(i)` multiple times in the same expression, you cannot do that. You need to use `b.end()-3, b.end()`. See the edit.

Comment: wow, didn't think that would make a difference, is there a reason why you have to reassign it to a different string first? thanks!

Comment: @parameter When `getPath` is returned by value, each call produces a different `std::string` object. Iterators that you get through `begin` and `end` are valid only within their own copy. If you pass iterators from different copies into any algorithm or a member function, such as `replace`, you get undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the -1 from your second argument.

```
string path = "filename.png";
path.replace(path.end() - 3, path.end(), "txt");
```

Results in path storing:

```
"filename.txt"
```

Because the first argument indicates where to start replacing characters, the second argument indicates where to stop (you stop AFTER replacing the last character, not 1 position before it), and the last argument specifies what to replace it with.

UPDATE:
In response to your updated question, your problem can be answered by asking your self what does dir.getPath(i) return?  A new instance of a string.  You're trying to traverse from an iterator in one string to an iterator in another string.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "..\\data\\images\\Test0.png" );

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    std::string::size_type pos;

    if ( ( ( pos = s.rfind( ".png" ) ) != std::string::npos ) ||
         ( ( pos = s.rfind( ".jpg" ) ) != std::string::npos ) )
    {        
        s.replace( pos, std::string::npos, ".txt" );
    }

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
..\data\images\Test0.png
..\data\images\Test0.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

For readers from the future:

Use the `<filesystem>` library to do this for you in one call to [std::filesystem::path::replace_extension](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/replace_extension):

```cpp
std::filesystem::path d = /* Path to directory */;
for(auto& dir_entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator{d}) {
    if(dir_entry.is_regular_file()) {
        auto& p = dir_entry.path();
        const auto ext = p.extension();
        if(ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".png") {
            p.replace_extension(".txt");
        }
    }
}
```